# Segmentation Fault in this C wrapper

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault, root, setuid

I am new to C and this is a simple wrapper(rootsetuidwrapper.c) written to execute scripts as a different user. The script I want to execute is ubuntu-server-secure.sh at path (/home/neehar) as root. My operating system is Ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS. Can someone help me fix these errors? I compiled with gcc and called the compiled code as rootsuidwrap by doing `gcc -o rootsuidwrap rootsetuidwrapper.c`. When I ran it in the terminal by doing ./rootsuidwrap ubuntu-server-secure.sh [0]. Is that the right way to call it? The usage part in the code says to do it this way. It comes up saying: `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`. Does it have to with this section of the code: `*user=cuserid(NULL);`. It could be rogue pointer. If so, what would be the fix and what would it look like?

It would be nice if someone could fix these errors and give me the working code. Also, I would like to know what I did wrong.

```
 * This program must be run as root to work.
 */

#if !defined(lint) && !defined(SABER) || defined(RCS_HDRS)
#endif /* !lint && !SABER || RCS_HDRS */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define TRUSTED_GROUP "trusted"

typedef enum { false = 0, true } bool;

#ifdef __STDC__
bool trusted(char *whoami)
#else
bool trusted(whoami)
  char *whoami;
#endif /* __STDC__ */
{
    char *user;
    char host[BUFSIZ + 1];
    char domain[BUFSIZ + 1];
    struct hostent *hp;

    /* 
     * Figure out whether this user on this host in this domain is
     * trusted.
     */

    /* 
     * Determine our domain name
     */
    memset (domain, '\0', sizeof domain );
    getdomainname (domain, sizeof domain - 1);

    /* 
     * Figure out our fully canonicalized hostname
     */

    memset (host, '\0', sizeof host );
    gethostname (host, sizeof host - 1);
    if ((hp = gethostbyname (host)) == NULL) {
      strcat (host, ".");
      strcat (host, domain);
      fprintf (stderr, 
               "%s: WARNING: can't canonlicalize hostname; assuming %s.\n",
               whoami, host);
    } else {
      strcpy (host, hp->h_name);
    }

    /* 
     * Get login name of current user
     */
    *user = cuserid (NULL);        
    if (user == NULL) {
      fprintf (stderr, " %s: You do not seem to be in the passwd file!\n",
               whoami);
      return false;
    }

    /* 
     * Look this triple up in the trusted netgroup 
     */

    return (innetgr (TRUSTED_GROUP, host, user, domain) == 1) ? true : false;
}


#ifdef __STDC__
main(int argc, char *argv[])
#else
main(argc, argv)
  int argc;
  char *argv[];
#endif /* __STDC__ */
{
    char *whoami;
    int ouruid;         /* uid we set to run chown and chmod */
    int proguid;        /* uid we are chowning program to */
    char *filename;
    struct stat statbuf;
    int error = 0;

    if (whoami = strrchr(argv[0], '/')) 
      whoami++;
    else
      whoami = argv[0];

    if (argc == 3)
      proguid = atoi(argv[2]);
    else if (argc == 2)
      proguid = 0;
    else {
      fprintf (stderr, "usage: %s filename [proguid]\n", whoami);
      exit(1);
    }

    filename = argv[1];

    if (trusted(whoami)) 
      ouruid = 0;
    else
      ouruid = getuid ();

    if (setuid (ouruid) == -1) {
      fprintf (stderr, "%s: Warning: setuid(%d) failed: ", whoami, ouruid);
      perror (NULL);
      exit (1);
    }

    if (stat (filename, &statbuf, sizeof(struct stat)) == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: failure statting %s: ", whoami, filename);
      perror(NULL);
      exit(1);
    }

    if (chown (filename, proguid, -1) == -1) {
      error++;
      fprintf (stderr, "%s: chown %d %s failed: ", whoami, proguid, filename);
      perror (NULL);
      fprintf (stderr, "continuing...\n");
    }

    if (chmod (filename, statbuf.st_mode | S_ISUID)) {
      error++;
      fprintf (stderr, "%s: chmod u+s %s failed: ", whoami, filename);
      perror (NULL);
    }

    return(error);
}
```

Help is appreciated,

Comment: Try debugging code using `gdb` and find out exact line number where the code is Seg-Faulting.

Comment: Why do you think the empty `#ifdef/#endif` block is a good idea? Why do you think the `#ifdef __STDC__` conditional compilation is a good idea?  Or, put differently, on which platform that you work on do you think there will be a non-standard compiler?  Let's face it, such systems must have a compiler that has willfully not been upgraded for almost 25 years, and they are very few and far between. (About the only case I know of is the C compiler on HP-UX that's used for rebuilding the kernel.  But you shouldn't be using that compiler for general development work such as this.)

Comment: I wrote this back in 1992 and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
user = cuserid (NULL);
```

Instead of

```
*user = cuserid (NULL);
```

While the program compiled, the compiler probably displayed a warning relating to this line.  I would study any other warnings you get compiling the program and work to remove them as well.

Comment: I changed it but, then I got an error when compiling it. It said assigns pointer to integer without a cast.